# Injecting custom navigation using a View Helper through the ServiceManager

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm just starting out developing for Zend Framework 2.  I'm trying to add a simple menu to my Application.  The menu will eventually be loaded from a database as user-definable bookmarks, so at the moment, I am trying to instantiate a view helper I've defined, add pages programmatically in the controller, and then inject the view helper's navigation into the view model.  My problem is that when I try to retrieve my view helper in the controller by using the ServiceLocator, I get a `ServiceNotFoundException`:

Application\View\Helper\ShortcutsMenu:

```
    namespace Application\View\Helper;

    use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;

    class ShortcutsMenu extends Navigation {

        public function shortcutsMenu() {
            //...
        }

        public function __construct() {
            //...
        }

    }
```

and in Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'view_helper' => array(
            'factories' => array(
                'shortcutsmenu' => function($sm) {
                    $smenu = new \Application\View\Helper\ShortcutsMenu();
                    return $smenu;
                }
            ),
        ),
    );
```

IndexController.php:

```
    $smenu = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('shortcutsmenu'); // throws ServiceNotFoundException
    //"Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for shortcutsmenu"

    $smenu->addPage(AbstractPage::factory(array(
        'label' => 'Homepage',
        'order' => '-1',
        'uri' => '/',
    )));

    // ...
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Edit:
The HTML I would like to generate in the application-wide layout would be something like:

```
<!-- Side tabs shortcuts -->
<ul id="shortcuts">
    <li class="current"><a href="./" class="shortcut-home" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="userpage1.html" title="My messages">My messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="/a/b/c?id=4" title="Bob's calendar">Bob's calendar</a></li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

probably using URI-style links rather than MVC ones.

Comment: Why do you want to extend `Zend\Navigation\Navigation`? If you just need to add pages there is no need to extend.

Comment: The HTML template we are using has two navigation systems - a traditional nested-list based template, and a sidebar of 6-7 icons, one on either side of the screen, that act like shortcuts.  My reasoning was that I would use the built-in menu view helper for the traditional menu, and create a new navigation helper for the shortcuts.

Comment: I have updated my answer how you can define your own helpers for rendering menu's etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to extend the navigation container `Zend\Navigation\Navigation` or extend the builtin view helpers to render menu's.

A [container](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.containers.html) manages all pages in the navigation structure. The are several ways to create a container.

All the [view helpers](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helpers.html) (menu, breadcrumbs) use the container as the provider for navigation data. You can eighter set a new container on the view helper using `setContainer()`. Alternatively you could just call the view helper in your view without a container setup and the view helper will create a new empty container for you.

If you need some alternate rendering because the default view helpers don't provide it you can create you own navigation view helper.

```
namespace MyNamespace\View\Helper\Navigation;

use Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\AbstractHelper;

class MyHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
}
```

Next register your view helper to the navigation pluginManager. I think you can do something like this (untested):

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap($e)
    {
        $application = $e->getApplication();
        /** @var $serviceManager \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager */
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();

        $pm = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('Navigation')->getPluginManager();
        $pm->setInvokableClass('myHelper', 'MyNamespace\View\Helper\Navigation\MyHelper');
    }
}
```

Now call you custom helper in your view:

```
$this->navigation()->myHelper()
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that to _render_ the menu, I should call the view helper from the view, something like:
`<!-- /user/content/shortcuts.phtml -->`
`<?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->render() ?>`
 But where are the pages added to the container?  Are they autofilled from the route?

Comment: Yes that's right, you can just add your pages in your view. `$this->navigation()->addPages()`.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm trying to do too much in the controller.  But this menu will require a collection of pages, pulled from a database.  I don't think that functionality goes in the view, does it?

Comment: I would do something like this. Create a seperate service class which has a dependency on your db driver and let it return a fully setup navigation container. Now set this container on your view helper `$this->navigation()->menu()->setContainer($myContainer)`. Now you have clean seperation of concerns and your controller is very light.