# zf2 - How do I add class names to li elements rendered by the navigation view helper?

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2

I am rendering a menu using the navigation view helper in zf2. I am using the config to specify my menu items and I don't want to use partials. When I add "class" to the navigation array in the config, it adds the class to the < a > element embedded within the < li > element. Does anyone know how to specify the class of a specific < li > elemenmt?

My config looks something like this:

```
"navigation" => array(
    "default" => array(
      "main" => array(
          'label' => 'Site',
          'route' => 'site',
          'class' => 'my-html-class-name',
          'pages' => array(
              'label' => 'Articles',
              'route' => 'articles',
              'pages' => array(
                  array(
                      'label'=> 'All Articles',
                      'route'=> 'all-articles'),
                ),           
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Which renders:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/site-map" class="my-html-class-name">Site</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/articles">Articles</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add the class name "my-html-class-name" to the parent < li > element instead of the < a > tag when the menu is rendered. How can I do this? I have posted a comment on the zf2 website, but I haven't got a response and [ZF2 custom attributes in navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037192/zf2-custom-attributes-in-navigation/18668315#18668315) isn't the solution that I am looking for.

Will I have to create a custom view helper to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply switch flag for `addClassToListItem` to `true` in navigation view helper:

```
<?php
echo $this->navigation('navigation')
    ->setAddClassToListItem(true)
    ->render();
?>
```

And then your class added for page which is already rendered to `<a>` element will also appear in parent `<li>` element.

Comment: That does it. Thanks!